# Hashtable output Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter, hashtable

Anybody can help me on response.write section? What it would be?

Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
Your post does not have much context to explain the code sections; please explain your scenario more clearly.

```
   public void Test()
    {

        Hashtable hs = new Hashtable();
        ArrayList a = new ArrayList();

        WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create(string.Format("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q={0}&rpp={1}&page={2}", "seni seviyorum", 20, 1));
        Stream s = wr.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s);
        string Sonuc = sr.ReadToEnd();

        hs = (Hashtable)JSON.JsonDecode(Sonuc);

        string from_user = hs["from_user"] != null ? hs["from_user"].ToString() : "";
        string to_user = hs["to_user"] != null ? hs["to_user"].ToString() : "";
        string text = hs["text"] != null ? hs["text"].ToString() : "";
        string profile_image_url = hs["profile_image_url"] != null ? hs["profile_image_url"].ToString() : "";
        string tweet_id = hs["id"] != null ? hs["id"].ToString() : "";
        DateTime created_at = hs["created_at"] != null ? DateTime.Parse(hs["created_at"].ToString()) : DateTime.Now;
        string twitter_url = string.Format("http://twitter.com/{0}/statuses/{1}", from_user, tweet_id);

        foreach (Hashtable oItem in (ArrayList)hs["results"])
        {
            Response.Write(oItem.?);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are best here to create a data structure that is better than a hashtable at storing the information in the results. I am sure there are plenty of examples of this.

I'm not sure what json library you have but I have had a lot of luck with newtonsoft.Json - installable by nuget.

So anyway the major issue here is that Hashtables aren't really great for getting data out of. As it is you can investigate the json returned and then figure out what the next level of element is.

Sniffing at the json you can see that the structure of hte return looks like this (at a guess I'd imagine this might be stored as an inner hashtable as well though I can't debug it to tell) :

```
{ "created_at" : "Fri, 23 Dec 2011 13:56:34 +0000",
    "from_user" : "Canboonn",
    "from_user_id" : 251744686,
    "from_user_id_str" : "251744686",
    "from_user_name" : "Bayram Can Avci",
    "geo" : null,
    "id" : 150213210446897152,
    "id_str" : "150213210446897152",
    "iso_language_code" : "tr",
    "metadata" : { "result_type" : "recent" },
    "profile_image_url" : "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/1700040754/IMG_8783_normal.JPG",
    "profile_image_url_https" : "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/1700040754/IMG_8783_normal.JPG",
    "source" : "<a href="http://twitter.com/">web</a>",
    "text" : "30 Aralik'a kadar 10 TL yüklersem her yöne 100 dakika, 100 sms ve 100 MB internet hediyeee, seviyorum seni #vodafone",
    "to_user" : null,
    "to_user_id" : null,
    "to_user_id_str" : null,
    "to_user_name" : null
  }
```

So you can go

```
foreach (Hashtable oItem in (ArrayList)hs["results"])
{
   Response.Write(oItem["from_user"]);
}
```

If this doesnt work then try look at the oItem.Keys property and see waht is in there. There might be a few more clues.

For example to write one of the properties of the result.